# New database not using the model configuration

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-express

On a SQL Server 2008 R2 Express instance, I have the "auto Close" option set to "False" on the [model] database.

However, When I execute `CREATE DATABASE [test];`, SQL Server creates the database with the `auto close` option set to `true`.

I checked `sys.configurations` just to make sure there was nothing pending (not the case).

I also tried to change the config on `[model]` to true, save, then change it back to false but I still have the same behavior.

If I create the database using the SSMS GUI (right click -> new database), it creates the database with the `auto close` option set to `false`

How can I make `CREATE DATABASE` create a database with `auto close` set to false?

Answer (score 2):

I finally found the answer in [Understanding SQL Express behavior: Idle time resource usage, AUTO_CLOSE and User Instances](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlexpress/2008/02/22/understanding-sql-express-behavior-idle-time-resource-usage-auto_close-and-user-instances/) by Mike Wachal of the Microsoft SQL Express team:

> Supporting ClickOnce is something we wanted to do with SQL Express, so we modified the behavior of the CREATE DATABASE functionality in SQL Express in order to set AUTO_CLOSE to True for all databases.

So I guess I'll have to put a trigger in place to change `auto close` back to `False` when a new database is created.